# assign different number to different intervals in r

Tags: r

In order to calculate correlation coefficient in R, I try to convert continuous variable into discrete variable. I want to assign different number to different intervals.

```
> min(data$price)
[1] 10000
> max(data$price)
[1] 1e+06
```

First of all, I would like to divide this variable into equal intervals and then assign them different values.The minimum price is 10000 and the maximum is 1000000, so if I divide the variable by small intervals(for example 1000), I will need to give a lot of numbers. Is there a function that makes it easier for me?

Comment: You may consider taking log() of the inputs and than ceil or floor them to make sure a ranges of values is getting a single value. For example logBase10(10000) = 4 and logBase10(9999) = 3.99...but after ceiling both of them will be 4.

Comment: (1) Do you mean [`cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html)? (2) *"I tried to use code discretize"* ... did you write a function, see it used somewhere, or just typed in `discretize(...)` and hoped that R would know what you mean? Whenever somebody says *"I tried"* but doesn't show the code attempted, we're still a little bit in the dark. (3) Your `$price` ranges from 1000 to 1e+06, okay ... what kind of intervals are you talking about? Consider making this reproducible by providing a sample of input data and your intended output of that data.

Comment: Great idea! but will the intervals be equal?

Comment: @Juli Avlokhashvili The intervals are equal but the number of members in each interval may not be equal....as it depends on data.

Comment: @hafiz031 Thank you so much.

Comment: @r2evans thank you too for your help :))